# Lucen.net returning only one hit

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

Hi i just started working on lucen.net today!!! After a lot of searches on net i found a approach to use it ..

I want to detect a word  from a txt file, which is on my local hard drive (D).
I am implementing like this

```
        string indexFileLocation = @"C:\Index";
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.Open(indexFileLocation);

        //create an analyzer to process the text
       Analyzer analyzer = new
        Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
       IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

       Document doc = new Document();

       Field fldContent = new Field
            ("text", System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\SampleDataFile.txt"),
            Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES);
        doc.Add(fldContent);
        indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
        indexWriter.Optimize();
   //   indexWriter.Commit();
        indexWriter.Dispose();
        string strIndexDir = @"C:\Index";
        Analyzer std = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "text", std);
        Query qry = parser.Parse("not");
        Directory Drct = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir));
        Searcher Srch = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(Drct,true));
        TopScoreDocCollector cllctr = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true);
        Srch.Search(qry, cllctr);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = cllctr.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
```

I am creating indexes in C folder...My text file just contains the [Macavity cat lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/sarahbrightman/macavitythemysterycat.html)

But the results of hits count i am getting are all wrong i tried

```
             word      |      hits 
             -------------------
            Macavity   |      1
              not      |      0
              And      |      0
              eyes     |      0
```

every word i tried are there in lyrics but they are not getting as hits..except Macavity which is giving hits 1, and if i added more words 'Macavity' in same line or in next line there is no change in hits...always it is 1.

Please someone help me

Answer (score 1):

A hit is a matched document, not a match within a document.  Since you have only one document, you will have a maximum of one hit.

Also, "not" and "and" are both default english stop words.  They will be eliminated by `StandardAnalyzer`, so you can not search for them.  It is usually not useful in practice to search for them, but if you really wish to be able to search for them, you can pass your own set of custom stop words into the `StandardAnalyzer` constructor.

Getting no matches on "eyes", though, seems odd.  Perhaps something odd about what is being read from the file.  I'd try debugging what `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\SampleDataFile.txt")` looks like.

Comment: thanx for d answer, and explanation ...  int results = topdoc.ScoreDocs.Length; is giving me correct results...